# Nested IF in a FOR with Razor in a CSHMTL page

Tags: c#, razor

I have a `IF~ statement in a`For Loop`in my`.cshtml` file.

Here is my code:

```
@foreach (var pet in Model.petDetails)
                {
                    <div class="row">
                        some text
                    </div>

                    <!-- added for dw-131-->
                    if ((string)Session[StaticStrings.pathName] == "somthing")
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;">
                                sometext @pet.somevar day
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
```

If i add a "@" sign in front of the `IF` statement i get an error. If i don't then the `IF` statement itself prints out on the screen. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: what is your "some text"  are you using any other @?

Comment: The page ends up prining "if ((string)Session[StaticStrings.pathName] == "somthing")" on the screen.

Comment: my "some text" is exactly the words "some text" without the quotes

Comment: sorry.. i see a little red underline in VS. THe error at runtime says that "@" is not needed if a block is open.

Comment: had a typo in my code. Its working now

Comment: Please delete it then.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the foreach in a `@{}` block:

```
`@{
    foreach (var pet in Model.petDetails)
                {
                    <div class="row">
                        some text
                    </div>

                    <!-- added for dw-131-->
                    if ((string)Session[StaticStrings.pathName] == "somthing")
                    {
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6" style="text-align:right;">
                                sometext @pet.somevar day
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
              }`
```

Comment: this does not solve the issue. No change in behavior

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use **@:** properly, eg:

```
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ProductViewModels.Count; i++)
  {            
       if (i % 2 == 0)
       {
           @:<div class="row">Row Title Text
       }

       <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="/product?id=@Model.ProductViewModels[i].Id">@Model.ProductViewModels[i].Title - @Model.ProductViewModels[i].Isbn13
          <br />
          <img src="@Model.ProductViewModels[i].ImageUrl" />
          </a>
       </div>

       if (i % 2 == 0)
       {
            @:</div>
       }            
   }
```